# java.lang.RuntimeException: writeValueXml: unable to write value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to successfully store and retrieve an arraylist of URIs. I'm not entirely sure where to put the 'storing' part, but it made sense to put it in onPause. My app crashes when I try to leave the activity though. I got a similar error when I tried to put it in onStop originally. Please help know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: my.package.myapplication, PID: 9357
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {my.package.myapplication/my.package.myapplication.Person1Screen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: writeValueXml: unable to write value content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A49684
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3395)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: writeValueXml: unable to write value content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A49684
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml(XmlUtils.java:710)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml(XmlUtils.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeSetXml(XmlUtils.java:356)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml(XmlUtils.java:693)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:300)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:269)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:235)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:192)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:600)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:515)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:536)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:458)
        at my.package.myapplication.Person1Screen.onPause(Person1Screen.java:257)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6557)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3381)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3354) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My onPause method is below. Person1Screen.java:257 is the editor.commit line at the end.

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet(happyList);
    editor.putStringSet(HAPPY_LIST, tempSet);
    editor.commit();
}
```

My retrieval in my onCreate (in case it helps):

```
// Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> tempSet = settings.getStringSet(HAPPY_LIST, null);
    if(tempSet != null)
        for (String str : tempSet)
            happyList.add(Uri.parse(str));
```

"happyList" is of type `ArrayList<Uri>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're performing an unchecked generic assignment from `HashSet` to `Set<String>`, where the set actually contains `Uri` objects. When you attempt to write this set to preferences, the code attempts to read a `String` but actually gets a `Uri` object, causing the crash. To fix this, you should convert your `Uri` objects back into `String`s.

So replace this line:

`Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet(happyList);`

with:

```
Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>();
for (Uri uri : happyList) {
    tempSet.add(uri.toString());
}
```

Comment: I just figured this out just before your posted. Had done exactly as you wrote and no crash.